# FTP Server on IIS10 in Port 990 Implicit Mode Only Works with Domain Firewall Off

Tags: ftp, sftp, iis, windows-server

I configured FTP server on Windows Server 2019, and got it all working fine, except that it will not work when the Windows Defender Firewall "Domain Networks" firewall is enabled.  The "Private Networks" and "Guest or Public Networks" firewalls ARE enabled, and everything works fine, as long as the "Domain Network" firewall is disable.

Note that this problem ONLY occurs when using port 990.  When using port 21 in either the STANDARD or the AUTH SSL-Explicit mode, the "Domain Networks" firewall can be ENABLED.  Since we do not wish to leave port 21 open, for now, we'll leave the Windows Defender firewall "Domain Network" firewall disabled on the server, as a temporary solution.

So the question is, why would enabling the "Domain Networks" firewall, cause the FTP service to stop working, only when using port 990?  A valid certificate is installed, and again everything works fine until ONLY the "Domain Network" fireware state is enabled.  Following are listings of the FTP messages from the server, when logging in via a CuteFTP client session.  The first listing is when the "Domain Network" firewall is ENABLED.  The 2nd listing is when the "Domain Network" firewall is DISABLED.

```
Firewall ENABLED:

STATUS:>    [2/1/2021 3:24:06 PM] Getting listing ""...
STATUS:>    [2/1/2021 3:24:06 PM] Resolving host name ftp.xxxx.com...
STATUS:>    [2/1/2021 3:24:08 PM] Host name ftp.edenusa.com resolved: ip = 12.xx.xx.88.
STATUS:>    [2/1/2021 3:24:08 PM] Connecting to FTP server... ftp.xxxx.com:990 (ip = 12.xx.xx.88)...
ERROR:>     [2/1/2021 3:24:30 PM] The connection failed due to an error or timeout.

1) Verify that the destination IP address is correct.
2) Increase the connection timeout threshold under Global Settings | Connection.
3) Switch to the opposite data connection type (PASV or PORT) under Site Settings | Type tab.
4) Verify that the problem is not local by trying to connect to an alternate server.
5) If a server name was used, verify it resolves to the correct address.
6) If using a local server table for server name resolution, check to see that it doesn't resolve to an obsolete address.
7) Try pinging the address.
8) If you are using a router, verify the router is up and running (check by pinging it and then ping an address outside of the router).
9) Do a traceroute to the destination to verify all routers along the connection path are operational.
10) Verify that your subnet mask is setup properly.
11) Verify that your local software or hardware firewall is not blocking outbound connections originating from CuteFTP.
12) Verify that your anti-virus software is not at fault (try disabling it).
STATUS:> [2/1/2021 3:24:30 PM] Waiting 30 seconds...
(Continues retry and loop over and over, with same errors)


FIREWALL DISABLED:

STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Getting listing ""...
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Resolving host name ftp.xxxx.com...
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Host name ftp.xxxx.com resolved: ip = 12.xx.x.88.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Connecting to FTP server... ftp.xxxx.com:990 (ip = 12.xx.x.88)...
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Socket connected. Waiting for welcome message...
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Connected. Exchanging encryption keys...
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Applying certificate chain verification using MS Trusted Root Certification Authority store.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This certificate is OK. Session Cipher: 0 bit 
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] SSL Connect time: 97 ms.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] SSL encrypted session established.
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 220 Microsoft FTP Service
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Connected. Authenticating...
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] USER xxxxx
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 331 Password required
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] PASS *****
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 230 User logged in.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Login successful.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] SYST
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 215 Windows_NT
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Host type detected: Windows NT.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] PWD
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 257 "/" is current directory.
STATUS:>  [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Home directory: /
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] FEAT
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Informational Message Only:
        211-Extended features supported:
         LANG EN*
         UTF8
         AUTH TLS;TLS-C;SSL;TLS-P;
         PBSZ
         PROT C;P;
         CCC
         HOST
         SIZE
         MDTM
         REST STREAM
        211 END
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This site supports features.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This site supports SIZE.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This site supports UTF-8.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This site supports LANG.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Setting up character encoding.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] LANG
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 200 Language is now English, UTF-8 encoding.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] OPTS UTF8 on
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 200 OPTS UTF8 command successful - UTF8 encoding now ON.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Using UTF-8.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This site can resume broken downloads.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] REST 0
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 350 Restarting at 0.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] PBSZ 0
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 200 PBSZ command successful.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] PROT P
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 200 PROT command successful.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] PASV
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 227 Entering Passive Mode (10,1,252,250,156,68).
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Substituting received PASV address 10.1.252.250 to server address 12.xx.x.88.
COMMAND:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] LIST
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Connecting FTP data socket... 12.xx.x.88:40004...
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 150 Opening ASCII mode data connection.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Connected. Exchanging encryption keys...
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] Applying certificate chain verification using MS Trusted Root Certification Authority store.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] This certificate is OK.
        Session Cipher: 0 bit 
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] SSL Connect time: 108 ms.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] SSL encrypted session established.
        [1/31/2021 4:37:25 PM] 226 Transfer complete.
STATUS:> [1/31/2021 4:37:26 PM] Directory listing completed.
```

Comment: The log shows a successful connection. Was the firewall on? Where does the problem arrive?

Comment: @harrymc, you're right and I thought about the fact that it might be somewhat confusing to show the successful login, but it shows a great deal of good information that might be useful.  So to answer your question, yes, the "Domain Networks" profile (1 of 3) is turned OFF, when the login is successful.  I will update the question with this information, and perhaps a screen shot of the Windows Defender Firewall.

Comment: Yes, it would be helpful to have the log for when the firewall is on.

Comment: @harrymc, the question has been edited to include the failure message.

Comment: We would need basically to also see your firewall rules and settings.

Comment: Well, that's the interesting part of this whole thing.  The rules are exactly the same for all 3 of the profiles.  Two of the profiles (Private networks and Guest or public networks) are enabled.  Only the "Domain networks" profile must be disabled to allow FTP to function.  I have a 2nd 2019 server that I am going to enable FTP on and see if the same issue occurs there.  Will report back.

Comment: @harrymc I figured this out and have posted the answer here.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I found that the issue was with the "Action" option under the "General" tab, which contains the following three radio button options:

( ) Allow the connection
( ) Allow the connection if it is secure
( ) Block the connection

Through trial and error, and looking at another Windows Server 2019 server, I found that the Microsoft DEFAULT value is the 1st radio button.  On this server, the 2nd radio button was selected for unknown reason.  This option has yet more options under the "Customize" button, with the default being "Allow the connection if it is authenticated and integrity-protected"  With the following information: "Allow only connections that are both authenticated and integrity-protected by using IPSec.  Compatible with Windows Vista and later."

Further research on why IPsec is not working will need to be performed, but for now, the Domain Networks firewall can be enabled, and we are able to connect to the FTP server through port 990 and SSL.